# How the struct and pointer acts

Tags: c, pointers, struct

While going through a quiz in SoloLearn app, I came across a certain code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct node{
    int a, b, c;
};
int main()
{
   struct node num = {3, 5, 6};
   struct node *ptr = &num;
   printf("%d\n", *ptr);
   printf("%d\n", *((int*)ptr + 1 + (3-2)));

    return 0;
}
```

I got the answer right as the result printing `3` and `6`, but I am not sure it I understood the *struct statement* and *pointer function* properly.

The following steps are how I understood how the code works.

1. Due to `struct node`, num 3, 5, 6 are set into `a, b, c` in the `num` variable.
2. `*ptr` points the first address of num due to `struct node *ptr = &num;` which means that it points to the address of the index = 0 which is `3` in {3, 5, 6}.
3. Therefore,  `printf("%d\n", *ptr);` prints `3`,
4. `printf("%d\n", *((int*)ptr + 1 + (3-2)));` is printing ***(0+1+1)** which is index = 2 of `num` which equals to `6`.

Is this right?

Comment: The `printf("%d\n", *ptr)` has undefined behaviour because the type of the argument passed is not `int`. Thus, there is no *right answer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but allow me to adjust your terminology. In particular, using the phrase "index" seems a little off to me, since we're not talking about an array. I will also break up your point#4 to be more explicit about what happens there.

1. Due to the initializer, 3, 5, 6 are set into a, b, c in the num variable.
2. `ptr` points to the *start address* of num due to `struct node *ptr = &num;`, which is the same as the address of `num.a`.
3. Therefore, `printf("%d\n", *ptr);` prints 3.
4. `(int*)ptr` yields a pointer to `num.a` with the proper type.
5. Adding 2 to `ptr` means that we add the size of two ints to the address. Note that the typecast is very important, as we would've otherwise added the size of two `struct node`s to the address; the effect of adding to a pointer depends on the pointer type.
6. The resulting address is the same as the address of `num.c`. At that address, we find the integer value of 6.

Comment: Wow. Now I get it. so it was actually a ```num.a``` rather than looking at it as an array. And the typecast was very important in ```printf("%d\n", *ptr);```. Thank you

Comment: `num` is a structure, not an array; the Standard requires that `&num` point to the first member `a`, but attempts to index into the `struct` via pointer arithmetic can fail since the implementation is free to add padding between members. The correct way to do this uses the [`offsetof` macro](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3).

Comment: I agree that this may not be portable in theory. In practice, I would be very surprised if it didn't work. This question is about understanding the effect of the given code, though -- not about how we would've written it. If it were, I would've skipped the `ptr` variable altogether, and just used `num.a` and `num.c`. ;)

Comment: is "3) Therefore, printf("%d\n", *ptr); prints 3." guaranteed? or is it undefined? at least some compiler would complain about mismatch type there?

Comment: Sorry, the articles 2 and 3 are utterly wrong. `*ptr` is not a pointer, so it cannot point  to anywhere. `printf("%d\n", *ptr);` has undefined behaviour: the type of `*ptr` is `struct node` but `%d` expects an integer.

Comment: Correct, changed #2 to `ptr` instead of `*ptr`.

Comment: #3 still makes no sense.